# como copiar texto con javascript con espacio de linea

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente código donde puedo copiar al portapapeles y funciona correctamente, el único inconveniente es que quisiera que se copiaran y tuvieran un salto de línea:

```js
const elemento = document.querySelector('.contenido-texto');

document.querySelector('#btn-copy').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.mensaje-copy').classList.add('show');
  copyToClipBoard(elemento);

  setTimeout(() => {
    document.querySelector('.mensaje-copy').classList.remove('show');
  }, 1300);
});

function copyToClipBoard(elemento) {
  const inputOculto = document.createElement('input');
  inputOculto.setAttribute('value', elemento.innerText);
  document.body.appendChild(inputOculto);
  inputOculto.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(inputOculto);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Kufam', cursive;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #f2f0f5;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.contenedor-principal {
  text-align: center;
}

.contenido-texto {
  margin: auto;
  background: #fff;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 30px 40px;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 30px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.contenedo-btnCopy {
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

.contenedo-btnCopy button {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.mensaje-copy {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 900;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.show {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.6s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Copiando al portapapeles</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kufam:wght@400;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="contenedor-principal">
      <h1>¡Copiando contenido al portapapeles con JS</h1>
      <div class="contenido-texto">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="contenedo-btnCopy">
        <button id="btn-copy">
          <i class="far fa-copy"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="mensaje-copy">
        <p>¡Copiado al portapapeles!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

En donde:

- **HTML:**
  En el HTML tengo el código donde esta el texto que quiero copiar.
- **CSS:**
  En el CSS están los estilos para que se vea bonito.
- **JS:**
  Aquí tengo que con evento de clic me permita copiar lo que tengo dentro del input.
  Pero aquí es donde quisiera tener la forma de copiar pero con saltos de línea.

---

Así me aparece este código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero así es como lo quisiera observar cuando lo pegue:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sucede que aquí estás creando un elemento `input`, y pasa que en un `input` los textos son de una línea, entonces, al hacer el copiado, el texto permanecerá en esa una línea.

```
const inputOculto = document.createElement('input');
```

La solución es crear un elemento `textarea` ya que en estos campos se permiten múltiples líneas (incluso los saltos de línea), y pues, al hacer el copiado, se copiará todo el valor del `textarea` incluyendo los saltos de línea.

---

Entonces, deberías cambiar esto:

```
const inputOculto = document.createElement('input');
inputOculto.setAttribute('value', elemento.innerText);
```

Por esto:

```
const inputOculto = document.createElement('textarea');
inputOculto.value = elemento.innerText;
```

---

Código completo:

```js
const elemento = document.querySelector('.contenido-texto');

document.querySelector('#btn-copy').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.mensaje-copy').classList.add('show');
  copyToClipBoard(elemento);

  setTimeout(() => {
    document.querySelector('.mensaje-copy').classList.remove('show');
  }, 1300);
});

function copyToClipBoard(elemento) {
  const inputOculto = document.createElement('textarea');
  inputOculto.value = elemento.innerText;
  document.body.appendChild(inputOculto);
  inputOculto.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(inputOculto);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Kufam', cursive;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #f2f0f5;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.contenedor-principal {
  text-align: center;
}

.contenido-texto {
  margin: auto;
  background: #fff;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 30px 40px;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 30px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.contenedo-btnCopy {
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

.contenedo-btnCopy button {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.mensaje-copy {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 900;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.show {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.6s;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor-principal">
  <h1>¡Copiando contenido al portapapeles con JS</h1>
  <div class="contenido-texto">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="contenedo-btnCopy">
    <button id="btn-copy">
      <i class="fas fa-copy"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="mensaje-copy">
    <p>¡Copiado al portapapeles!</p>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4d529f15e3.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ya veo, el problema de que se copia todo en una sola línea reside aquí:

```
const inputOculto = document.createElement('input');
```

Sucede, que un elemento `<input>` es de una sola línea y, a pesar de que tu `elemento.innerText` devuelve lo siguiente:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
```

Cuando lo pasas al `value` de tu `<input>` este convierte el contenido a una sola línea.

Necesitas un elemento que soporte multilínea, como es el caso del `<textarea>`:

```
const textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
```

Simplemente reemplaza:

```
const inputOculto = document.createElement('input');
inputOculto.setAttribute('value', elemento.innerText);
```

Por:

```
const textarea        = document.createElement('textarea');
      textarea.value  = contenido.innerText;
```

---

Veamos esta corrección aplicada a tu código:

```js
const contenido   = document.querySelector('.contenido-texto');
const boton       = document.querySelector('#btn-copy');
const mensaje     = document.querySelector('#btn-copy');

boton.addEventListener('click', () =>
{
    mensaje.classList.add('show');
    copyToClipboard(contenido);

    setTimeout(()=>
    {
        mensaje.classList.remove('show');
    },
    1300);
});

function copyToClipboard(contenido)
{
    const textarea        = document.createElement('textarea');
          textarea.value  = contenido.innerText;
          
    document.body.appendChild(textarea);
    
    textarea.select();
    
    document.execCommand('copy');
    
    document.body.removeChild(textarea);
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Kufam', cursive;
}

body{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #f2f0f5;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

h1{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.contenedor-principal{
    text-align: center;
}

.contenido-texto{
    margin: auto;
    background: #fff;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    padding: 30px 40px;
    text-align: justify;
    line-height: 30px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.contenedo-btnCopy{
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding-right: 40px;
}

.contenedo-btnCopy button{
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 15px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.mensaje-copy{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-weight: 900;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

.show{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .6s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Copiando al portapapeles</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kufam:wght@400;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="contenedor-principal">
        <h1>¡Copiando contenido al portapapeles con JS</h1>
        <div class="contenido-texto">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="contenedo-btnCopy">
            <button id="btn-copy">
                
                <i class="far fa-copy"></i>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="mensaje-copy">
            <p>¡Copiado al portapapeles!</p>
        </div>
    </div>

  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Hector, me ayudo muchisimo a conocer mi problema. :D

Comment: Oh... fuiste más rápido :-) le doy +1!

Comment: @Cris223511.dev Igual te doy +1 porque tu respuesta es igual de válida que la mía, y encima, no está en construcción. xD

Comment: Al parecer demoré más en construirla XD, pero vamos, la tuya quedó perfecta :-)